# Django not translating the site properly

Tags: django, python-2.7, internationalization, django-i18n

After spending too many hours on this, StackOverflow is for the rescue.

I configured my settings.py as below:

```
...
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', u'English'),
  ('de', u'German'),
  ('fr', u'French'),
)

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
...
```

In my `base.html` file, I have a form as below:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

My `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^$', 'MainApp.views.index'), #root
)
```

In the same `base.html` file, I have on top `{% load i18n %}` and in the body, I have a sample `{% trans "This is the title." %}`. Before running the server, I did:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
django-admin.py makemessages -l fr
```

The sample text above was picked up by `makemessages`, and I provided the respective translations for `msgstr`. After that, I did `django-admin.py compilemessages.` The command ran nicely and generated the *.mo* files in the respective locale folders.

I run the server and the the form does not work. From a another StackOverflow post, I was hinted to remove the `#, fuzzy lines`, which I did. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `LocaleMiddleware` after the `SessionMiddleware` in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
....
)
```

The order of middleware classes is important. The `LocaleMiddleware` uses session data to detect the user language, so it must come after the `SessionMiddleware`. It is also mentioned in the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Let's hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I moved Locale down, and boom kaboom it worked!

Comment: @ppetrid Could you please take a look at my post to see if you can help me? I am having almost the same problem as this one but couldn't figure out how to solve this isse. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615394/internationalization-not-working-properly-no-action-seems-to-be-happening?sfb=2